# How can I make this overlay cover the whole thumbnail

Tags: css

So I would like to cover the whole thumbnail when hovering over, so that the overlay content fills the whole image, 100% by 100%. So the overlay should cover only image(whole size of it), not more than that.

Here's the pen to demonstrate the current state: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbJgoe

```
.about__images {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about__inner {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.about__inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.about .about__inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.about .about__inner:hover .about__inner--overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

<div class="container about">
  <div class="about__images">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="" class="hideonhover">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the overlay to cover the entire `.about__inner` or just the size the the image in it?

Comment: @Pangloss I would like it to cover the image, thanks for pointing that out, I will edit the question

Comment: Since it's Bootstrap the layout is responsive, so consider both larger and smaller viewports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close  to it. Just a small modification in structure and a few lines in css:

HTML:

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="about__inner">
           <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="" class="hideonhover">

           <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>


        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
.about__inner{
 position:relative;
}
.about__inner--overlay{
  color:#fff;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/oYwKLO

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want it to do, but I would like to keep the text as well (lorem)

Comment: Texts on overlay ?

Comment: Yeah,  <p>lorem</p>  should be over the image as well

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `absolute` positionning and size the box. You may use coordonates to size the box so it fits any size since you already set the parent in `relative` positionning..

```
.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  top:0;
  left:15px;
  right:15px;
  bottom:0;
  color:white;
  position:absolute
}
```

```css
.about__images {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about__inner {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.about__inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.about .about__inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  top:0;
  left:15px;
  right:35px;
  bottom:0;
  color:white;
  position:absolute
}

.about .about__inner:hover .about__inner--overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container about">
  <div class="about__images">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="" class="hideonhover">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about__inner col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300" alt="">
        <div class="about__inner--overlay">
          <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.about__inner {
  padding: 0px; //for full frame image
}
.about__inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; //force image display as cover, no scale
}
.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  position: absolute; //You need it to arrange the div.
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:


.about__images {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about__inner {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.about__inner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.about .about__inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about .about__inner .about__inner--overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.about .about__inner:hover .about__inner--overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 185px;
  top: -185px;
}
```